# Linux deniega lectura de archivo aún teniendo permisos en Bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell-script, sh

Tengo que realizar un script en Bash como ejercicios de clase. No hemos tocado casi Bash y nos han mandado esto:

> Crea un script en Bash que emule el famoso juego de AHORCADO, puedes usar las herramientas y la lógica que desees siempre y cuando no afecte a la funcionalidad del juego mismo.

Había pensado que para escoger las palabras, he descubierto que Linux tiene un archivo de diccionario. Entonces quería escoger una palabra aleatoria de ese archivo, que encuentra en `/usr/share/dict/spanish`, y pasar el texto del archivo a uno para escoger 2 palabras de manera aleatoria.

O al menos escoger una palabra al azar del diccionario me valdría.

Puedo leerlo sin permisos de administración ni nada, es decir un cat o un less de siempre.

Tengo este código, pero la salida al ejecutar el script me dice:

> línea 5: /usr/share/dict/spanish: Permiso denegado.

Lo que quiero que haga este código para probar que me lee bien el archivo es recibir el contenido e imprimir las palabras, luego ya iré filtrando y haciendo lo que tenga que hacer...

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#   Se añade a array diccionario
DICTIONARY=(`"/usr/share/dict/spanish"`)
#   Función 
function string_to_array(){
    for t in "${DICTIONARY[@]}"
        do
        echo $t
    done
    echo "Contenido del archivo en el ARRAY"
}
string_to_array
```

Comment: Agregaste permisos al archivo??, pues de lo que entiendo tu tienes permisos.

Comment: Si, el archivo .sh tiene permisos de ejecución, incluso con sudo, además el archivo tiene permisos de lectura que es lo que quiero, mira:

arm@ARM-Ubuntu:/usr/share/dict$ ll
total 3240
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 852190 may  4  2018 spanish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que estás usando mal el archivo.

Al escribir `$("/usr/share/dict/spanish")`, le estás pasando como programa o ejecutable el mismo archivo, y pues ese archivo: 1) Ni es un programa o ejecutable, 2) Ni tiene permisos de ejecución (y ni debería tenerlos).

Lo que te serviría sería el [builtin `readarray`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html):

```
$ readarray -t palabras < /usr/share/groff/1.22.4/eign
$ echo ${palabras[1]}
i
$ echo ${palabras[10]}
that
```

Yo utilicé el archivo */usr/share/groff/1.22.4/eign* porque es el que tengo en mi WSL. En tu caso sería algo como:

```
$ readarray -t palabras < /usr/share/dict/spanish
```

Y podiendo obtener las palabras con `${palabras[n]}`, donde "n" es un entero mayor o igual a 0.

Comment: Genial me ha funcionado, me han dicho también que funcionaria con VAR=($(</usr/share/dict/words))

Comment: Que bueno que te haya funcionado. No necesariamente te funcionará con `VAR=$(< ...)`. De eso depende la variable IFS. SI haces eso, puede que en tu array tengas todo el contenido del texto pero sólo en el campo 0, es decir, el primero. Yo **no te recomendaría** la aproximación del `var=$(< ...)`